# How to retrieve the total row count of a query with TOP

Tags: sql-server, count, pagination, aggregate

I have a SQL Server 2008 query

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM T
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

I'd like to get also the total number of the rows. The obious way is to make a second query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Is there an efficient method?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want a second query?

```
SELECT TOP 10
    *, foo.bar
FROM
    T
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS bar FROM T WHERE ...) foo
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY
    ...
```

OR

```
DECLARE @bar int
SELECT @bar = COUNT(*) AS bar FROM T WHERE ...
SELECT TOP 10
    *, @bar
FROM
    T
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS bar FROM T WHERE ...) foo
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY
    ...
```

Or (Edit: using WITH)

```
WITH cTotal AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS bar FROM T WHERE ...)
)
SELECT TOP 10
    *, cTotal .bar
FROM
    T
WHERE
    ...
ORDER BY
    ...
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid a second query. Maybe with WITH instruction or temp tables? I'm not expert of sql server

Comment: Examples 1 and 3 are single queries and functionally identical.

Comment: Ok, I mean I'd like to avoid a second "table scan". I'd like to make the engine to scan only once the table, in order to retrieve the total count and the n rows.

Comment: You can't. They are 2 different query constructs. The COUNT will actually be quite efficient, probably more so than the main query because it will use the most efficient

Answer (score 4):

What is in this answer seems to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125458/16241

Basically you do a:

```
SELECT top 100 YourColumns, TotalCount = Count(*) Over()
From YourTable
Where SomeValue = 32
```

TotalCount will have the total number of rows.  It is listed on each row though.

When I tested this the query plan showed the table only being hit once.

Comment: The execution plan does show that this query hits the table only once, but it is way slower than any of the options given in the [answer by gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610974), for reasons unknown to me. Your code however looks simpler, and is better suited for using with large queries already existing in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ORDER BY clause from the 2nd query as well.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`SQL Server` doesn't keep `COUNT(*)` in metadata like `MyISAM`, it calculates it every time.

**UPDATE:** If you need an estimate, you can use statistics metadata:

```
SELECT  rows
FROM    dbo.sysindexes
WHERE   name = @primary_key,
```

where `@primary_key` is your table's primary key name.

This will return the `COUNT(*)` from last statistics update.

Comment: are you saying in mysql, you can do "SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE...LIMIT 0,20" and there's meta data for the total number of rows in memory?  So that I don't have to make a second query with COUNT()?

Comment: OH, I just answered my own question...SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() does the job..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     TOP (2) *,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM T) AS C
FROM         T
```

Comment: Would this not do "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM T" for every output row? In this case 10 rows

Comment: I haven't profiled this, but I think this would actually be slower since it is in a sub-query and returned in each row. I'm no guru though, the server might be smart enough to cache it. Even still, I don't think it would be any *faster* than two queries since it is still running them both.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought -

Implement stored procedure with below parameters:

1. @TotalCount  (default 0)
2. @PageSize
3. Required filter parameters.

Return 2 result set at first time.

1. Total Count SQL statement - Return as @TotalCount (execute only if Input parameter TotalCount = 0)
2. Top @PageSize count as required using @TotalCount

Hope this will work. Not tried but logically it will work.