# can I get count() and rows from one sql query in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I'd like to get the total count of results and top n rows of some query - is it possible
in one statement?

I'd expect the results as:

```
count(..) column1        column2
125         some_value   some_value
125         some_value   some_value
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes possible. Please refer the below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610932/how-to-retrieve-the-total-row-count-of-a-query-with-top

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 --optional
    MC.Cnt, M.Column1, M.Column2
FROM
    myTable M
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM myTable) MC
```

Edit: After downvote and COUNT/OVER answer. A comparison on 2 tables of mine

You can see a huge difference between my CROSS JOIN/simple aggregate and a COUNT/empty ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS C, key1col, key2col
FROM myTable

(24717 row(s) affected)

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 49865, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'myTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 77, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

StmtText
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
       |--Table Spool
       |    |--Segment
       |         |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDB].[dbo].[myTable].[IX_useful]))
       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:((1)))
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1005],0)))
            |    |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=Count(*)))
            |         |--Table Spool
            |--Table Spool

SELECT
    MC.Cnt, M.key1col, M.key2col
FROM
    myTable M
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM myTable) MC

(24717 row(s) affected)

Table 'myTable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 154, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.


StmtText
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1009],0)))
       |    |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1009]=Count(*)))
       |         |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDB].[dbo].[myTable].[IX_useful]))
       |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDB].[dbo].[myTable].[IX_useful] AS [M]))
```

I've repeated this on a table with 570k rows and here is the IO

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 3, logical reads 1535456, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'myTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2929, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.


Table 'myTable'. Scan count 34, logical reads 6438, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: +1 for pulling all your guns out. I'll have to check out my exec plans.

Comment: @Chris Bednarski: I've been bitten before! Also SET STATISTICS TIME ON si useful: CPU is x5 to x10 and duration x2 for the OVER solution for me

Comment: @gbn: I'm now interested to see if there is much difference in performance between 2005 & 2008. It runs like a dog on 2005.

Comment: @Chris Bednarski: please let us know: chatting about this with my colleagues earlier about this

Comment: @gbn: I added some more comments

Comment: By the way on the logical reads front the two figures are not directly comparable. [See this answer for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230838/why-are-logical-reads-for-windowed-aggregate-functions-so-high/5194902#5194902).

Answer (score 6):

what about

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS C, COLUMN1, COLUMN2
FROM TABLE
```

Regarding `CROSS JOIN` queries
In a heavy `INSERT`/`DELETE` environment, the cross join will return incorrect row count.

Try this from multiple connections
connection 1

```
set nocount on;
drop table dbo.test_table;
GO
create table dbo.test_table
(
    id_field uniqueidentifier not null default(newid()),
    filler char(2000) not null default('a')
);
GO
create unique clustered index idx_id_fld on dbo.test_table(id_field);
GO
while 1 = 1
insert into dbo.test_table default values;
```

connection 2

```
select T2.cnt, T1.id_field, T1.filler
from dbo.test_table T1
cross join (select COUNT(*) as cnt from dbo.test_table) T2

select T2.cnt, T1.id_field, T1.filler
from dbo.test_table T1
cross join (select COUNT(*) as cnt from dbo.test_table) T2

select T2.cnt, T1.id_field, T1.filler
from dbo.test_table T1
cross join (select COUNT(*) as cnt from dbo.test_table) T2
```

Each time, the count of records (`@@ROWCOUNT`) is different to `T2.cnt`

In the case of `COUNT(*) OVER()`, there is only a single table scan and the `@@ROWCOUNT` is always the same as `T2.cnt`

Regarding query plans - SQL 2005 SP3 appears to be much weaker at doing `COUNT(*) OVER()` than SQL 2008 R2. On top of that, it incorrectly reports query costs (I never thought a sub query could cost more than 100% of the entire query).

In a lot of scenarios, the cost of the `COUNT(*) OVER()` is between 50-75% of the `CROSS JOIN`

The best case scenario for a cross join would be if there was a very narrow index to do the count on. That way there will be a clustered index scan for the data + an index scan for the count.

As always, it's best to measure, measure, measure and go with the compromise that you're happy to live with.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same(ish) thing

Comment: much better than joins, uses a single scan only

Comment: This is the preferred method.

Comment: Have you compared performance to my one? Runs like a dog. It has to spool up the COUNT in a WorkTable

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do this with a `CROSS JOIN` and CTE, but it's not very efficient:

```
WITH Rows_CTE AS
(
    SELECT Column1, Column2
    FROM Table
    WHERE (...)
)
SELECT c.Cnt, r.Column1, r.Column2
FROM Rows_CTE r
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Rows_CTE) c
```

I think a better way to get what you want would be to use a single query but multiple *result sets*, which you can do by using `COMPUTE`:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM Table
WHERE (...)
COMPUTE COUNT([Column1])
```

Comment: Why use a CTE? A simple cross join onto a derived table will do it. And COMPUTE is deprecated too.

Comment: @gbn: I did use a `CROSS JOIN`.  The CTE is so that the predicates can be reused (note the inclusion of `WHERE (...)`, which is missing from the question but probably included in the production environment).  And I know `COMPUTE` is technically deprecated, but `ROLLUP` can't replace it here and using `COMPUTE` eliminates an entire table/index scan from the plan.

Comment: Frankly, it's always annoyed me that they deprecated `COMPUTE`, because it's still the *only* way to compute aggregates without a `GROUP BY` clause.  But that's a rant for another day.

Comment: I like COMPUTE too. Damn useful.

Answer (score 0):

give a try for this query:

```
select ColumnId,Descr,(select COUNT(*) from ColumnSetUp)as c
from ColumnSetUp
group by ColumnId,Descr
```