# How do I get rowcount of a cte in a separate dataset?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have identified a way to get fast paged results from the database using CTEs and the Row_Number function, as follows...

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 1
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 2

DECLARE @Customer TABLE (
  ID       INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  Name     VARCHAR(10),
  age      INT,
  employed BIT)

INSERT INTO @Customer
    (name,age,employed)
SELECT 'bob',21,1
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'fred',33,1
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'joe',29,1
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'sam',16,1
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'arthur',17,0;


WITH cteCustomers
     AS ( SELECT
            id,
            Row_Number( ) OVER(ORDER BY Age DESC) AS Row
          FROM   @Customer
          WHERE  employed = 1 
     /*Imagine I've joined to loads more tables with a really complex where clause*/
     )       

SELECT
  name,
  age,
  Total = ( SELECT
              Count( id )
            FROM   cteCustomers )
FROM       cteCustomers
INNER JOIN @Customer cust
  /*This is where I choose the columns I want to read, it returns really fast!*/
  ON cust.id = cteCustomers.id
WHERE      row BETWEEN ( @PageSize * @PageNumber - 1 ) AND ( @PageSize * ( @PageNumber ) )
ORDER      BY row ASC
```

Using this technique the returned results is really really fast even on complex joins and filters.

To perform paging I need to know the Total Rows returned by the full CTE. I have "Bodged" this by putting a column that holds it

```
Total = ( SELECT
              Count( id )
            FROM   cteCustomers )
```

Is there a better way to return the total in a different result set without bodging it into a column? Because it's a CTE I can't seem to get it into a second result set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using a temp table first, I'd use a CROSS JOIN to reduce the risk of row by row evaluation on the COUNT

To get total row, this needs to happen separately to the WHERE

```
WITH cteCustomers
     AS ( SELECT
            id,
            Row_Number( ) OVER(ORDER BY Age DESC) AS Row
          FROM   @Customer
          WHERE  employed = 1 
     /*Imagine I've joined to loads more tables with a really complex where clause*/
     )       

SELECT
  name,
  age,
  Total
FROM       cteCustomers
INNER JOIN @Customer cust
  /*This is where I choose the columns I want to read, it returns really fast!*/
  ON cust.id = cteCustomers.id

CROSS JOIN

(SELECT Count( *) AS Total FROM   cteCustomers ) foo

WHERE      row BETWEEN ( @PageSize * @PageNumber - 1 ) AND ( @PageSize * ( @PageNumber ) )
ORDER      BY row ASC
```

However, this isn't guaranteed to give accurate results as demonstrated here: 
[can I get count() and rows from one sql query in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2798094/27535)

Edit: after a few comments.

How to avoid a CROSS JOIN

```
WITH cteCustomers
     AS ( SELECT
            id,
            Row_Number( ) OVER(ORDER BY Age DESC) AS Row,
            COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total --the magic for this edit
          FROM   @Customer
          WHERE  employed = 1 
     /*Imagine I've joined to loads more tables with a really complex where clause*/
     )       

SELECT
  name,
  age,
  Total
FROM       cteCustomers
INNER JOIN @Customer cust
  /*This is where I choose the columns I want to read, it returns really fast!*/
  ON cust.id = cteCustomers.id
WHERE      row BETWEEN ( @PageSize * @PageNumber - 1 ) AND ( @PageSize * ( @PageNumber ) )
ORDER      BY row ASC
```

Note: YMMV for performance depending on 2005 or 2008, Service pack etc

Edit 2:

[SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/) shows another technique where you have reverse ROW_NUMBER. Looks useful

Comment: Why isn't it " guaranteed to give accurate results" ?

Comment: @digiguru: See my link to the other question please for a working example

Comment: @gbn: It seems like your other example is accurate. There is no-one disputing the accuracy of the result set.

Comment: @digiguru: My answer is actually wrong there compared to Chris Bednarski's answer. He demonstrates that a CROSS JOIN can give inaccurate results under high load. The correct way (Chris B's way) is COUNT..OVER but.. ah ha.. we can work it into your query... will update

Comment: Hey check this out: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/ allows an even faster technique

Comment: @digiguru: kinda obvious when you look at it. Good find.

Comment: @digiguru - Paul White looked at this method and concluded ["This method is the slowest overall, with high CPU usage, a large memory grant, and the largest number of physical reads."](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/70120/)

Answer (score 1):

@Digiguru

OMG, this really is the wholy grail!

```
WITH cteCustomers
AS ( SELECT id,
         Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY Age DESC) AS Row,
         Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC)
            + Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) - 1 AS Total /*<- voodoo here*/
      FROM   @Customer
      WHERE  employed = 1
      /*Imagine I've joined to loads more tables with a really complex where clause*/
   )
SELECT  name,  age,  Total
  /*This is where I choose the columns I want to read, it returns really fast!*/
FROM cteCustomers
INNER JOIN @Customer cust
ON cust.id = cteCustomers.id
WHERE row BETWEEN ( @PageSize * @PageNumber - 1 ) AND ( @PageSize * ( @PageNumber ) )
ORDER BY row ASC
```

So obvious now.

Comment: I wouldn't get too excited about this one. [See some performance figures here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/70120/)

Comment: I guess there's no free lunch.